# Why should the primary winding of the transformer not be grounded?

Tags: transformer, ac, grounding

I've been wondering what would happen if you grounded both star points of a Y/Y connected transformer. This shouldn't affect the voltages,  so why really is it not advised to earth both the primary and secondary star points of a transformer?

Any information on this will be appreciated.

Comment: what  if the 3 sides are not balanced?

Comment: You forgot to mention the type of the transformer. There are 3 and 5 limb types, makes  a lot of difference.

Comment: If the primary star point is not grounded and one phase connection is broken, the voltage over both remaining windings will be substantially lower than the voltage between a phase and ground.

Comment: Doesn't the primary side have an earth-to-neutral bond already?

Comment: Who advises to not earth both star points?  There are thousands of intertie transformers in the power grid with both Y winding star points connected to earth.  You can't always extrapolate advice for 1 application to a wider rule.